# Problem: Armature deforms mesh opposite of bone positions

Tags: mesh, rigging, armature

I have a character made of 5 different parts, each with 5 different meshes and armatures (one for each limb and one for the head and torso). All armatures have been parented to the 5 meshes with automatic weights.

[image: 5 different meshes, 5 different armatures]

3 of the armatures work properly.

[image: Working armature]

The other 2 act differently.

[image: Misbehaving armature]

Wherever the bones are placed, the mesh deforms in the opposite way. I've tried recalculating the normals on the mesh, as well as lining up the origins of the meshes and armatures, but this problem persists. What is a possible solution?

[image: Still image of armature problem]

Here's the .blend:
[image]

Comment: Select the mesh and [Ctrl]+[A]>rotation. this will apply the rotation of the mesh which may have been flipped when you mirrored.

Comment: I just did that and the problem remains. Should I share the .blend file?

Comment: probably the best. use a service like http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/315/

Comment: It was the scale. will answer. one sec

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You needed to apply the scale. Select the affected meshes and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> > *Scale*. Now tab into editmode and recalculate all the normals.

You now need to reparent the meshes to the armature

[image]

Comment: All of the affected parts were scaled to -1